How to reload the previous initialized fancytree?
I am trying to reload a previously initialized fancytree. I am now using the fancytree 2.38.3. I have a search functionality for title or number on the tree and I need to reload without the selection highlight.
Before 2.31.0:
$("#tree").fancytree("destroy");
pageTree();

window.pageTree = function() {
   $("#tree").fancytree({...options});
};

After 2.38.3, jQuery 3.7.1:
Uses the same code but triggers an error.
Fancytree assertion failed: only init supported
I tried to use the below code but triggers same error.
var $tree = $.ui.fancytree.getTree("#tree");
$tree.destroy();
pageTree();


Please create a minimal reproducible example

Here is the example with the HTML structure:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>FancyTree Reload Example</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.fancytree/2.38.3/skin-win8/ui.fancytree.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.fancytree/2.38.3/jquery.fancytree-all-deps.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="search-input" placeholder="Search...">
    <button id="search-button">Search</button>
    <div id="tree"></div>
</body>
</html>


Here is the example with the Javascript structure:
function initializeTree(data) {
    $("#tree").fancytree({
        source: data,
        // ... other options ...
    });
}

function destroyAndReinitializeTree(data) {
    // Destroy the existing FancyTree instance
    var $tree = $.ui.fancytree.getTree("#tree");
    if ($tree) {
        $tree.$div.fancytree("destroy");
    }

    // Initialize a new FancyTree instance
    initializeTree(data);
}

function searchTree(query) {
    // Implement your search logic here
    var newData = getSearchResults(query);

    // Destroy and reinitialize the tree with new data
    destroyAndReinitializeTree(newData);
}

function getSearchResults(query) {
    // Example search logic (replace with actual search logic)
    return [
        { title: "Search Result 1", key: "1" },
        { title: "Search Result 2", key: "2" }
    ];
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Initial tree setup
    initializeTree([
        { title: "Node 1", key: "1" },
        { title: "Node 2", key: "2" }
    ]);

    $("#search-button").on("click", function() {
        var query = $("#search-input").val();
        searchTree(query);
    });
});


